# how to remove header & footer from login page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to remove header & footer from login page.

I tried following code.but its not working.
Can you anyone help me on this?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
        <referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

Comment: What's your file name?

Comment: customer_account_login.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you add that code? Also the root reference is not required.

I created entered the below code into `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml` and it worked, you may need to change header.container to a different block depending how much of the header you want to remove. This will remove ALL the header leaving only the nav and the login/register content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: You can find most the layout block/container named in vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: can you be specific regarding this path? thanks!

Comment: Do you mean where I've entered **VENDOR**/**THEME**? If so this is just the name of your store and the theme

Comment: I meant **vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** I couldnt find where is **magento/module-theme**

Comment: That is the full path, if you have installed Magento via Composer you should have a vendor directory which contains all the code. If you have installed via another method the same code may be in `app/design/frontend/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` but I've never seen it done this way.

Comment: @BenCrook i was able to remove header and footer but it contains its js and css file

Answer (score 3):

For magento 2.2.4, use ,`footer-container` as **footer container**.

use below code:

```
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show header with respect to customer login/logout

add this in body of file
`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="vendor\module\Block\Headerlinks" name="history-link" after="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>    
        </referenceBlock>
```

and in file `Headerlinks` add

```
    <?php
namespace vendor\module\Block;


class Headerlinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = [],
         \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        if ($customer->isLoggedIn()) {
             $link = '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('customer/account/') . '" title="Account & Security">Account & Security</a></li>';
             $link .= '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('sales/order/history/') . '" title="Purchase History">Purchase History</a></li>';
        return $link;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```